# How to configure nginx to proxy to a soap webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to config a nginx server on an EC2 instance:

What I have done are:

1. nginx listening 443 with ssl configured
2. there is a webservice deployed on the ec2 localhost:8086/applications/, this is what I want nginx to proxy to

What I have now is:

```
location /applications/.* {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8086
  proxy_redirect default
}
```

but this doesn't work, when I try POST with url `https://<ip>/applications/?wsdl` the nginx error.log reads like below:

```
 [error]15692#0 *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/applications/index.html" is not found (2: No    such file or directory), client <my_ip>, server: , request "POST /applications/ HTTP/1.1", host: <the_host_ip>
```

Very noob about nginx here, your help will be appreciated, or direct me to wherever documenting this kind of config please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some `;`s missing in your configs and I don't think you need `/applications/.*` on your `location`

Try something like this:

```
listen       80;
server_name  your.website.com;

location /applications {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Make sure you **don't** have something like this:

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the following example code. The version of nginx is 1.8.0.

```
    listen       5554;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://soap.example.com;                     
    }
```